# Can I close the program from the Main constructor?

Tags: c#, multithreading, screen, loading, program-entry-point

Can you exit an application before the constructor is finished and the main form is loaded?

At startup, I have a loading screen that displays before the main form is loaded.  The loading screen is displayed from the constructor before the constructor has finished.

I do something similar with an exit screen by using a variable between the main form and the exit screen. I have an application exit in the main form if the exit screen returns true.

Finally, should all the thread/class/loading/program setup be done in the main constructor or am I doing it wrong?

#### Update:

I mean after the program.cs and in the static main

```
namespace app
{
 public partial class app1 : Form
 {
   public app1()
   {  
      InitializeComponent();
      // open loading screen
      // initialize vars
      // create objects
   }
 // form opens when app1() finishes
```

1. Is `app1()` the right place to initialize everything?
2. If I try to send a "close" message back from the loading screen before `app1()` is finished, it doesn't work - the process still runs even though nothing is open.

Answer (score 11):

I've found that if I try to kill my application from the main form constructor when I still have the splash screen showing on a different thread (which looks similar to what you are doing), that `Application.Exit()` does not work, but `Environment.Exit(-1)` does.

Answer (score 6):

try this,

```
    public partial class MyForm : Form
    {        
    public MyForm()
    {
     if (MyFunc())
        {
            this.Shown += new EventHandler(MyForm_CloseOnStart);
        }
    }

    private void MyForm_CloseOnStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         this.Close();
    }
    }
```

it will work well...

Comment: The same thing using a lambda: `Shown += (sender, e) => Close();`

Answer (score 0):

Which main constructor of which class?

Are you talking about the static method `Main` that has a default location in the `Program` class?

You use that method to do initialization that needs to occur before you open any windows on screen.

Obviously, if you need to use a loading screen, you will probably want to move some code somewhere else, as you need a message loop around forms, and the message loop will block until your form closes.

If you return from the Main method before you open any form, then no form will be shown obviously.

Having said all that, I feel your question is a bit vague and I'm pretty sure I didn't understand exactly what it is that you're asking.

First and foremost, `Main` is not a constructor, it's just a static method.

Answer (score 0):

When main thread ends:

- background threads are "killed/abandoned"
- foreground threads (the default when creating threads) are waited till they finish.

Answer (score 0):

you can break constructor only via throwing an exception. To do that surreptitiously, throw you own specific exception.

```
class ConstructorAbortedException : Exception { }

class Foo
{
  public Foo()
  {
    if(goesWrong)
    {
      throw new ConstructorAbortedException();
    }
  }
}

void Bar()
{
  try
  {
    Foo f = new Foo();
  }
  catch(ConstructorAbortedException)
  {
    //..
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As jontsnz answered, the code with 

`Environment.Exit(-1)` 

works fine in the constructor, but this causes the application to throw an "Application Hang" event, which can be seen as an error in the Windows Event Viewer. Using 

`Environment.Exit(0)` 

exits without registering an error though, so I prefer that one.